# How can you calculate depth of a binary tree with less complexity?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Given a binary search tree t, it is rather easy to get its depth using recursion, as the following:

```
def node_height(t):     
    if t.left.value == None and t.right.value == None:
        return 1
    else:
        height_left = t.left.node_height()
        height_right = t.right.node_height()
        return ( 1 + max(height_left,height_right) )
```

However, I noticed that its complexity increases exponentially, and thus should perform very badly when we have a deep tree. Is there any faster algorithm for doing this?

Comment: The size of the tree increases exponentially with the height (twice as many nodes on each subsequent level, assuming a full balanced tree).  There is no avoiding traversing all paths in general because you don't know which path might be the tallest.  That is, unless you have some simplifications for us?

Answer (score 3):

If you store the height as a field in the Node object, you can add 1 as you add nodes to the tree (and subtracting during remove).

That'll make the operation constant time for getting the height of any node, but it adds some additional complexity into the add/remove operations.

Comment: This sounds clever if you always need to read the height of nodes in your tree, but you will have to maintain these values, which means you have to override all the tree operations to maintain the height values.

Comment: Rewrite, not necessarily override

Comment: @cricket_007 Little clarification, which I tried to address in my answer. Simply adding 1 as you add nodes could be misinterpreted. If you do an insert recursively, you would want to update the height field **after** the node has been added to the tree. So, `height=1+max(left child's height, right child's height)` should do the trick, and it will be a constant time op. But, nice answer overall. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

This kind of extends from what [@cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) mentioned in his answer.

So, if you do a `( 1 + max(height_left,height_right) )`, you end up having to visit every node, which is essentially an O(N) operation. For an average case with a balanced tree, you would be looking at something like `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(1)`.

Now, this can be improved to a time of O(1) if you can store the height of a certain node. In that case, the height of the tree would be equal to the height of the root. So, the modification you would need to make would be to your `insert(value)` method. At the beginning, the root is given a default height of 0. The node to be added is assigned a height of 0. For every node you encounter while trying to add this new node, increase node.height by 1 if needed, and ensure it is set to 1 + max(left child's height, right child's height). So, the height function will simply return node.height, hence allowing for **constant time**. The time complexity for the insert will also not change; we just need some extra space to store `n` integer values, where `n` is the number of nodes.

The following is shown to give an understanding of what I am trying to say.

```
          5 [0]

- insert 2 [increase height of root by 1]

          5 [1]
         / 
        /   
   [0] 2 

- insert 1 [increase height of node 2 by 1, increase height of node 5 by 1]

          5 [2]
         / 
        /   
   [1] 2    
      / 
     /   
[0] 1  

- insert 3 [new height of node 2 = 1 + max(height of node 1, height of node 3) 
                                 = 1 + 0 = 1; height of node 5 also does not change]

          5 [2]
         / 
        /   
   [1] 2     
      / \
     /   \
[0] 1     3 [0]

- insert 6 [new height of node 5 = 1 + max(height of node 2, height of node 6) 
                                 = 1 + 1 = 2]

          5 [2]
         / \
        /   \
   [1] 2     6 [0]
      / \
     /   \
[0] 1     3 [0]
```